# Screenshots with Selenium RC

Tags: screenshot, selenium-rc

Is there a way to take a screenshot of JUST the browser window using Selenium RC? I am able to use the captureEntirePageScreenshot and the captureScreenshot methods but neither are what I want... My goal is to create screenshots, of a certain size, as the Selenium script runs and then be able to include those screenshots in a document. I know how to set the size of the browser window... so if there is a way to take a screenshot of ONLY the browser window, I'd have the images I need.